# Live video streaming architecture using Parse?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform

Fact: To provide a Live video streaming using Parse I have to host the video content on another service such as AWS.

What I don't understand (if you can help me) is how the UI + Parse + AWS is glue? and also how is data flowing.

Which scenario is right? Let's imagine a client hit a page where they can see some live streaming video then???

**scenario 1**: **AWS** sits on the middle and glue the UI and Parse.

> UI -> request -> **AWS** -> request -> Parse -> return data to -> UI (client gets content from **AWS**).

**scenario 2**: **Parse** sits on the middle and glue the UI and AWS.

> UI -> request -> **Parse** -> request -> AWS-> return data to -> UI (client gets content from **Parse**).

**scenario  3**: The UI requests **both** servers at the same time.

> UI -> request -> AWS -> return data to -> UI. (client gets content
> from **both**).
>
> UI -> request -> Parse -> return data to -> UI. (client
> gets content from **both**).

As you can see, I have no idea how everything is glue. Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Host the content using AWS S3 or whatever you like and then use cloud code web hooks to access the resources

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't get it. You @Russell answered to me a similar question some weeks ago (thanks!) but who is in the middle? Is the UI talking to AWS? or is Parse the one talking to the UI? or is it both??

Answer (score 1):

That's a very tough question to answer without having a greater understanding of the platform and design.

For example, if the ability to watch the video streams requires authentication, then you will want to verify the user with Parse before providing a secure connection to the AWS resource ([such as CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/)).

If authentication is unnecessary, then you could directly view and access the video streams using [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) and it's associated client SDKs or using REST calls.

Most likely, both services will need to be in constant communication with each other and with your clients. Parse could keep track of which users are actively streaming videos being hosted by AWS, user preferences, and so on while AWS is providing the videos.

Going back to your example, this would most closely fit scenario 3, which is where all 3 elements will be in constant communication with each other.

Comment: Thanks! I found an example here that explain in detail most of what you said: http://blog.parse.com/learn/building-a-killer-webrtc-video-chat-app-using-pubnub-parse/ (Y)

Comment: Great find! I hadn't seen that before and was an interesting read.